# How to bind Date of DateTimeOffset not UtcDate in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, datetimeoffset

In this .cshtml "StartDate" type is DateTimeOffset.

And when it's viewed on Web Site,Date is displaying of It's UtcDate, not the Date, which containing the Actual result.

As Start Date is 18-May-2016 00:00:00.... +05:30, and Output should be 18-May-2016, but is displayed 17-May-2016.

Please suggest way to bind actual date.

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you show us relevant code for your current situation?

Comment: It's as :  <span data-bind="text:$data.StartDate()"></span> in .cshtml page.

Comment: I Believe the only way you are going to get this to work the way you want is to use moment.js, or remove the offset and display the date with the offset time added to it.

Comment: From  where you are getting start date. Can add code here

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MattJohnson, Thanks for suggesttion